# Чтение текстового файла по словно

Tags: c++

Нужно прочесть файл F.txt пословно, подсчитать количество повторяющихся слов и записать в другой текстовый файл слова в алфавитном порядке. Подскажите, как это сделать?

Comment: Задачу следуют более точно формулировать. Например у Vlad from Moscow слегка другой алгоритм, который считает количество повторений каждого слова. А из вопроса сложно однозначно понять что именно нужно.

Comment: Упоминание `F.txt` в тексте вопроса однозначно свидетельствует об учебном задании.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Читать файл пословно весьма странная затея. Для начала файл достаточно просто читать теми средствами что предлагает язык или стандартная библиотека. В c++ для работы с файлами присутсвуют [файловые потоки](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/). Для чтения - [std::ifstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/), для записи [std::ofstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/). Самый простой вариант - прочитать размер файла, выделить память целиком под этот размер и полностью считать файл. Для больших файлов это нерационально. В этом случае можно выделить буфер значительно меньшего размера и читать файл порционно, но это усложнит алгоритм обработки. После прочтения файла в буфер, следует пробежаться по последнему и тем или иным способом выделять отдельные слова (слова могут быть разделены только пробелами или учитывать любые другие символы разделители).

Для подсчета повторяющихся слов удобно из входящего буфера копировать слова в `std::string`, завести счетчик повторяющихся слов и контейнер `std::set<std::string>`. Каждое слово добавляем в контейнер, функция вставки возвратит false если слово уже есть в контейнере, соответственно это сигнал увеличивать счетчик повторений.

Для вывода слов в алфавитном порядке достаточно пробежаться оператором `for` по предыдущему контейнеру. Эта операция выдаст список слов в алфавитном порядке, правда там не будет повторяющихся слов, все слова будут в единичном экземпляре.

Comment: По условию нужно не количество повторений, а количество слов которые повторяются.

Comment: @Cerbo что есть количество повторений и количество слов которые повторяются и чем эти понятия отличаются? Мой вариант с одним счетчиком находит именно количество слов которые повторяются, то-есть подсчитываются только те слова, что встречаются более одного раза. И это к-во характеризуется одним счетчиком независимо повторяется много раз одно слово или несколько слов.

Comment: именно об этом я и писал

Comment: @Cerbo В таком случае правильно формулировать вопрос так - посчитать отдельно для каждого повторяющегося более одного раза слова количество его повторений. Потому как это подразумевает множество счетчиков, то-есть множество количеств, а у ТС слово количество в единственном числе.

Comment: да нет же у вас правильно, просто не ясно про условие увеличения счетчика написано

Answer (score 1):

Делается это с использованием стандартного контейнера `std::map<std::string, size_t>` и перегруженных операторов ввода и вывода `operator >>` и `operator <<`  для стандартных потоков ввода-вывода.

Answer (score 0):

Можна считывать посимвольно и поставить условие, чтобы считывало до пустого знака (\0 кажется). Загнать в цикл, который будет считать слова через strcmp.

Comment: А вы могли бы код набросать, так что бы я на пальцах понял что к чему?

Comment: Извини, дружище, голова своим забита доверху, не смогу тебе тут помочь. Могу поподробнее написать алгоритм, но не код.

Comment: Это тоже очень поможет, буду крайне признателен.